# How can i setup a webserver with TLS and DH_anon?

Tags: webserver, tls

I need to setup a test web server with TLS and DH_anon . Apache or nginx is preferred, but not mandatory. OS is als not important. I already tried a google search, but there seems to be very limited information about DH_anon.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to setup a test web server with TLS and DH_anon

Make sure your cipher list is `ADH` only.

From OpenSSL's [`ciphers(1)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html) (and ignoring the vanity ciphers), I believe there will be eleven of them:

```
* SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5      EXP-ADH-RC4-MD5
* SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5            ADH-RC4-MD5
* SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA   EXP-ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
* SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA            ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
* SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA       ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA
* TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA        ADH-AES128-SHA
* TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA        ADH-AES256-SHA
* TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256       ADH-AES128-SHA256
* TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256       ADH-AES256-SHA256
* TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256       ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384       ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

---

> Apache or nginx is preferred...

For `nginx`, I believe the setting of interest is [`ssl_ciphers`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule#ssl_ciphers).

As for TLS (and reading *not* SSL), then use `!SSLv2 !SSLv3`. For nginx, I believe the setting of interest is [`ssl_protocols`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule#ssl_protocols).